# How to show $\Bbb Z[x]/<3,x^2+1>$ is field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

My attempt

First I wanted to show $<3,x^2+1>$ is maximal 
So, I supposed another maximal $A$ which contain $<3,x^2+1>$ properly, and choose element $a$ in $A \setminus <3,x^2+1>$ to induce $A$ must contain $1$. But this approach can be applied only to the case of $\Bbb R[x]$

Second, by failure to above approach, I want to show that  $\Bbb Z[x]/<3,x^2+1>$ is isomorphic to $Z_5[x]$ because I already know about $Z[i]/<2-i>$ is isomorphic to $Z_5[x]$. So I preferentially narrowed down given ring into the case of $Z[x]/<x^2+1>$. As result of the investigation, all elements of the ring could be expressed by $a+bi+<x^2+1>$ with assuming $x=i$ Thus I can conclude that $Z[x]/<x^2+1>$ is isomorphic to $Z_5[x]$ which is field. But I cannot connect this result with our given ring.

I want to get some advice from your help. Since I don't learn about the polynomial ring such as association with irreducible property(?). So please give me a hint to prove that by using basic property of field.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, it is possible to simply compute the quotient ring. Below are some hints to guide you, but first let me make a remark.

In $\Bbb Z[x]/(3,x^2 + 1),$ the class of $3$ (i.e., $3 + (3, x^2 + 1)\in\Bbb Z[x]/(3,x^2 + 1)$) is equal to $0,$ because $$3 - 0 = 3\in (3,x^2 + 1).$$ Thus, $\Bbb Z[x]/(3,x^2 + 1)$ cannot be isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_5[x],$ as $3\neq 0$ in $\Bbb Z_5[x].$

**Hint 1:**

> Use the following fact: if $R$ is a ring and $a,b\in R,$ $$R/(a,b)\cong (R/(a))/(b)\cong (R/(b))/(a).$$ That is, if you have an ideal generated by multiple elements, you can quotient by those elements in any order to compute the quotient ring.

**Hint 2:**

> Here's another useful fact: Let $R$ be a ring and let $a\in R$ be some element. If $S$ is the quotient ring $S = R/(a),$ then $R[x]/(a)\cong S[x].$

**Hint 3:**

> Fact: if $k$ is a field, and $f\in k[x],$ then $k[x]/(f)$ is a field if and only if $f$ is irreducible.

**Hint 4:**

> One last fact: if $k$ is a field and $f\in k[x]$ has degree less than or equal to $3,$ $f$ is reducible over $k$ if and only if $f$ has a root in $k. $ That is, if $\deg f\leq 3,$ then $f$ is reducible over $k$ if and only if there exists $a\in k$ such that $f(a) = 0.$

Comment: your hint will be helpful when I study polynomial ring later on. So I need to prove all your hint and apply those to prove given problem. anyway thank you so much. It makes my thought organized.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. By the division algorithm, we can write $$P(x)=Q(x)(x^2+1)+r(x)$$
where $Q(x),r(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ are defined uniquely such that $\deg(r)<2$. Hence $r(x)=ax+b$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Write $\overline{P(x)}$ for the the class of $P(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\left\langle 3,x^2+1\right\rangle$, then the above yields $\overline{P(x)}=\overline{r(x)}$. Since $3\in \left\langle 3,x^2+1\right\rangle$ any multiple of $3$ is killed as well, hence $$\overline{P(x)}=(a\mod3)\overline{x}+(b\mod 3)\overline{1}
.$$

So any element of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\left\langle 3,x^2+1\right\rangle$ can be written as $$ax+b$$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}_3$. It is clear that this quotient is a commutative ring with unit, hence we only need to show that any (non-zero) element has an inverse. You can do this explicitly: Indeed, notice that

$$(ax+b)(ax-b)=a^2x^2-b^2=-(a^2+b^2) \:\:\;\;\;\;\;\;\mbox{ in }\:\:\;\;\mathbb{Z}[x]/\left\langle 3,x^2+1\right\rangle$$
From the above equation you can easily find general inverses.

Comment: Thank you, I understand all your comment!

Comment: Sir, can you explain last few lines of your answer? How $$(ax+b)(ax-b)=a^2x^2-b^2=-(a^2+b^2) \:\:\;\;\;\;\;\;\mbox{ in }\:\:\;\;\mathbb{Z}[x]/\left\langle 3,x^2+1\right\rangle$$? and how we can find inverses of each nonzero element using this?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi :  Certainly. The first equality $(ax+b)(ax-b)=a^2x^2-b^2$ is just a straightforward calculation (which holds in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Clearly, the equality $a^2x^2-b^2=-(a^2+b^2)$ is false in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. To show that $a^2x^2-b^2=-(a^2+b^2)$ holds in $\mathbb{Z}[X]/\left\langle 3,x^2+1\right\rangle$ we need to show that the difference of the two sides $a^2x^2-b^2+a^2+b^2\in \left\langle 3,x^2+1\right\rangle$. Note that $a^2x^2-b^2+a^2+b^2=a^2(x^2+1)\in \left\langle 3,x^2+1\right\rangle$. This shows the equality.

Comment: Informally, $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\left\langle 3,x^2+1\right\rangle$ is the ring obtained from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ by "killing" or "annihiliting" multiples of $3$ and multiples of $(x^2+1)$. By that I mean that every time you encounter $3$, you just put it equal to $0$ and similarly $x^2+1=0$ (or equivalently, $x^2=-1$).

Comment: So how does the above help to get inverses? Let $P(x)$ be any non-zero element in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\left\langle 3,x^2+1\right\rangle$. By my answer, $P(x)=ax+b$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}_3$ (not both zero). Since $$(ax+b)(ax-b)=-(a^2+b^2),$$ we find that $$(ax+b)^{-1}=\frac{ax-b}{-(a^2+b^2)}.$$ Here off course, you have to wonder what I mean by $\frac{1}{c}$ when $c\in \mathbb{Z}_3$, but this is simply the multiplicative inverse of $c$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: Sir, Thank you so much...